# Converting uint32_t to network byte order

Tags: c, networking, client-server, endianness, uint32-t

i'm doing stuff for my studies, so yeah, it's *homework*.

First: I got a working Java Server Application, i also had this client application i'm writing in c now working in java.
Simple as is, i fail at sending the uint32_t to my java server.

So let's show off some code:

```
char* callString(char func, char* str, uint32_t anz) {

  uint32_t packageLength, funcLength, strLength;
  funcLength = htonl(sizeof(func));
  strLength = htonl(strlen(str));
  uint32_t byte = htonl(4);
  uint32_t trailing = htonl(1);
  anz = htonl(anz);

  packageLength = byte + byte + funcLength + byte + strLength + byte + byte + trailing;
  /*packageLength = htonl(packageLength);*/

  char byteBuffer[ntohl(packageLength)];


  printf("%i\n", packageLength);
  printf("%i\n", htonl(packageLength));
  printf("%i\n", ntohl(packageLength));

  sprintf(byteBuffer, "%i%i%c%i%s%i%i%c", packageLength, byte, func, byte, str, byte, anz, '\0');

  printf("%s\n", byteBuffer);

  if(write(sock, byteBuffer, packageLength) < 0) {
    printf("write: Konnte keine Daten zum gegenüber senden.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  char* retVal = "hallo";
  return retVal;
}
```

Simple as is, i call this function with func = 'v', str = "hallo" and anz = 2
which will give me a packageLength of 27 bytes.

Package is build like this:
  = packageLength (int) which is 4 byte
  + length of function descriptor (funcLength) which is 4 byte
  + func descriptor (func) which is funcLength
  + length of param1 (strLength) which is 4 byte
  + length of value of param1 (str) which is strLength
  + length of param2 which is 4 byte
  + length of value of param2 (anz) which is 4 byte
  + NULL Byte (\0) which is 1 byte

I assume the conversion i do is wrong maybe i'm using the wrong datatype. On server-side i use the Java ByteBuffer to collect the data. At first i read the 4 byte packagelength from the network which will give me the information of how long i have to read until i get the whole data package:

```
byte[] msgLength = new byte[4];
try {
handle.getInputStream().read(msgLength);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("could not receive byte stream: msgLength");
    break;
}
ByteBuffer receive;

receive = ByteBuffer.wrap(msgLength);

int packageLength = receive.getInt();
System.out.println("packageLength" + packageLength);
```

The last println will give me the following output:

> packageLength875901497

So does anyone now where my problem is? I can provide you with more code if necessary but i think the error is either the datatype (uint32_t) or the conversion.

Help is appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
funcLength = htonl(sizeof(func));
strLength = htonl(strlen(str));
uint32_t byte = htonl(4);
uint32_t trailing = htonl(1);
anz = htonl(anz);

packageLength = byte + byte + funcLength + byte + strLength + byte + byte + trailing;
```

You're converting the sizes to network order and *then* adding them together for `packageLength`. You should add them together *before* converting them to network order with `htonl`.

Apart from that, all this:

```
sprintf(byteBuffer, "%i%i%c%i%s%i%i%c", packageLength, byte, func, byte, str, byte, anz, '\0');
```

is wrong, because I assume you want to send them as binary, but using `sprintf` as above would send them in their base 10 ASCII representation (i.e. you're sending the numbers as text!)

Comment: This was some trial and error pieces i did. But i changed it again and i get like this
  <code>
    uint32_t packageLength, funcLength, strLength;
    funcLength = sizeof(func);
    strLength = strlen(str);
    anz = htonl(anz);

    packageLength = 4 + 4 + funcLength + 4 + strLength + 4 + 4 + 1;
    /*packageLength = htonl(packageLength);*/
    strLength = htonl(strLength);
    funcLength = htonl(funcLength);
    uint32_t byte = htonl(4);
    uint32_t trailing = htonl(1);

    char byteBuffer[packageLength];

    packageLength = htonl(packageLength);
  </code>

Comment: In Java i had a ByteBuffer were i put the data, which had given me the methods .putInt() .put() to put things in a bytebuffer and then send the ByteBuffer. I didn't know a way to pack my data as to put it in an char array.

Comment: Nonetheless i get on server-side with changed code (see above) the same packageLength: packageLength875901497 How can i tell c to write my data in binary to the socket?

Comment: *(int *) (byteBuffer + _offset_) = some_int;

Comment: And something like memcpy for strings

Comment: I don't understand this line of code sorry. what's the matter with that *(int *) in front of it?

Comment: Dereferencing part of the buffer as an int. Perhaps you should read a C book?